# how to use 2 box-shadow on a single button

Tags: css

I want exactly matched button with gradient and Box-shadow.

I tried gradient css3 properties (box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #333;) but couldn't meet the expected result. Can anyone Suggest me the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not getting what you want but I'm trying according to your question.

You can use 2 color box-shadow and advance gradient use like this:-

```
.answer-btn {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    min-width: 267px;
    padding: 18px 0 19px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: inset 1px #2894cc;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color rgba(38, 144, 202, 0.11);
    background-color: #278abe;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4gPHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PGRlZnM+PHJhZGlhbEdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgY3g9IjUwJSIgY3k9Ii0yNSUiIHI9IjEwMCUiPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiM0MWJlZTgiLz48c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMyNjhhYmQiLz48L3JhZGlhbEdyYWRpZW50PjwvZGVmcz48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2dyYWQpIiAvPjwvc3ZnPiA=');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(50% -25%, ellipse farthest-side, #41bee8, #268abd 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% -25%, ellipse farthest-side, #41bee8, #268abd 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-side at 50% -25%, #41bee8, #268abd 100%);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 7px 0px 0px #1b6b9e, 0px 0px 10px 1px #b3b3b4;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 0px 0px #1b6b9e, 0px 0px 10px 1px #b3b3b4;
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 0px 0px #1b6b9e, 0px 0px 10px 1px #b3b3b4;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-size: 1.5625rem;
}
.answer-btn:active {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 5px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 5px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 5px);
    transform: translate(0px, 5px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kant707/9zLLpLbg/